# UIImageView & CGAffineTransformScale, getting wrong path

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimage, transform, scale

I'm trying to add a border to image (UIImageView), everything works fine except one thing: when i'm resizing image i'm getting larger ( or smaller) shape. Here's some code:

```
 CGPoint center = view.center; // view is a UIImageView
 CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
 CGFloat angle = [(NSNumber *)[view valueForKeyPath:@"layer.transform.rotation.z"] floatValue];
 CGFloat scale = [(NSNumber *)[view valueForKeyPath:@"layer.transform.scale"] floatValue];
 transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, center.x, center.y);
 transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, scale, scale);
 transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, angle);
 transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, -center.x, -center.y);
 CGPathRef path = CGPathCreateWithRect(view.frame, &transform); // looks like the problem is here
 shape.path = path; // shape is a CAShapeLayer
 CGPathRelease(path);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by replacing

```
CGPathRef path = CGPathCreateWithRect(view.frame, &transform);
```

with

```
CGPathAddLines(path, nil, points, 5);
```